# What to do about blatantly off-topic non-English questions which were answered?

Tags: discussion, questions

From time to time I encounter questions asked in a language other than English, which remained on the site due to the inefficiency of the current system. Take the following question for example: [WARN: Establishing SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762514/warn-establishing-ssl)
It has gone through the Triage review with 3 people flagging for closure, but it never received any close votes and the flags expired. Someone posted low quality answer, which prevented the question from being roomba'd.

When I find such question I can cast my close vote, but I have no guarantee it will be closed, before my vote also expires. There is nothing, which would need moderator attention also. If it was an answer I would just flag as NAA and it would be deleted by moderators, but if it is a question I can't do anything.

What can I do about such questions? Just cast my close/down vote or flag for moderators attention?

Comment: @HereticMonkey It doesn't really answer my question, because I know the policy in general. The linked answers don't really explain what to do with such question which has already received answers.

Comment: There's always the close-vote chat room. One can post a request there - just read the room's FAQ first so that you don't (as happens to me) do it in an incorrect way...

Comment: And yet, what you do is the same as what you do with questions which have not already received answers. Namely, vote to close as unclear (or whatever the new name is). Feel free to edit the answer to include this specific wrinkle if you desire.